# Invalid URL for using an IP adress on webhook URL - Watson Assistant

Tags: api, server, webhooks, ibm-watson

I want to connect watson assistant to an API running on a server. But I don't know why it gives the error "Invalid URL".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`192.168.*.*` is [a *private* IP address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network). Watson won't be able to access it. You need a *publicly accessible* URL. For testing purposes, you can expose your server via [something like ngrok](https://ngrok.com/).